# Posting JSON format from Google script to PandaDoc API

Tags: json, pandadoc

I am trying to create a new document in PandaDoc via de Google Scipt editor.

Everything works fine (document is created with the right name and template), but the recipients don't come through. If I post the same parameters with Postman the recipients do come through. It probably has to do with the format of the recipient parameters but I am not experienced enough to see what.

Here is my code:

```
function createPandaDoc() {
   var formData = {
     "name": "Sample Document5",
     "template_uuid": "BDZRbdUt7abCbYFBBBREaL",
     "recipients": [
       {
         "email": "john@appleseed.com",
         "first_name": "John",
         "last_name": "Appleseed",
         "role": "Signer"
       }
     ]
   };

 // Because payload is a JavaScript object, it will be interpreted as
 // as form data. (No need to specify contentType; it will automatically
 // default to either 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
 // or 'multipart/form-data')


 var options = {
   'method' : 'post',
   'headers' : {
      Authorization : 'Bearer xxx',
      contentType : 'application/json'
   },
   'payload' : formData
 };

 UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.pandadoc.com/public/v1/documents', options);
}
```

If you have any idea, please let me know!

Thanks Chris

Answer (score 1):

Got it! Should have been:

```
function createPandaDoc() {
   var formData = {
     'name': 'Sample Document5',
     'template_uuid': 'BDZRbdUt7abCbYFBBBREaL',
     'recipients': [
       {
         'email': 'john@appleseed.com',
         'first_name': 'John',
         'last_name': 'Appleseed',
         'role': 'Signer'
       }
     ]
   };

 // Because payload is a JavaScript object, it will be interpreted as
 // as form data. (No need to specify contentType; it will automatically
 // default to either 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
 // or 'multipart/form-data')


 var options = {
   'method' : 'post',
   'contentType' : 'application/json',
   'headers' : {
      Authorization : 'Bearer xxxx'
   },
   'payload' : JSON.stringify(formData)
 }

 UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.pandadoc.com/public/v1/documents', options);
}
```